# Php error on connecting to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote my code like this

```
<?php
    $dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost" "XXXXXXXX" "XXXXXXXXX" );

    if(mysqli_errno()){
        echo "Cannot connect:" .mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

but this is my error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"XXXXXXXX"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\connection.php on line 2

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic - the solution is to fix a simple typo (missing comma).

Answer (score 5):

You need commas to separate the parts in your connection:

```
 $dbCon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "XXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXX" );
```